# How to show html file from specific folder in webView on Android

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

In storage, I have one folder and this folder name is: **my_app**
In this folder I have one **HTML** file and i want open this **HTML** file into `webView`!

I write below codes, but after run application show me this error on `webView`: **Web page not available** and not open my **HTML** file!

**My codes:**

```
htmlReaderPage_reader.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
htmlReaderPage_reader.setInitialScale(1);
htmlReaderPage_reader.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
htmlReaderPage_reader.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
htmlReaderPage_reader.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
htmlReaderPage_reader.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
htmlReaderPage_reader.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
htmlReaderPage_reader.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
htmlReaderPage_reader.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
htmlReaderPage_reader.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
htmlReaderPage_reader.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

**For open from storage I write below codes:**

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/my_app/index.html");
String uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(file.getAbsolutePath())).toString();
htmlReaderPage_reader.loadUrl(uri);
```

But when open this HTML file from assets folder, open this file and not have any error!

**For open from assets I write below codes:**

```
htmlReaderPage_reader.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/my_app/index.html");
htmlReaderPage_reader.loadUrl(uri);
```

Why open this file from **assets** but not open from **storage**!

I should open this from storage and a specific folder!

Comment: You stil are not checking if the file exists with file.exists().

Comment: Log your String uri and tell us the value.

Comment: `Uri.fromFile(new File(file.getAbsolutePath())).toString()`. That makes no sense. You can simply write `Uri.fromFile(file).toString()`

Comment: Are you on Android Q?

Comment: You have not done what i asked you to do in your first post. You have not answered all my questions there. Should all be done again?

Comment: @blackapps, i sure this file is exists! and yes i used android Q

Comment: Being shure does not matter. Use the file.exists(). Answer the question of the other post too. And this post.